# Append key data from the GO MAP

Tags: string, dictionary, go

I have a map in GO of the type :

```
var userinputmap = make(map[string]string)
```

The values in it are like :

```
userinputmap["key1"] = value1
userinputmap["key2"] = value2
userinputmap["key3"] = value3
```

How can I generate a string that contains al the above keys in comma seprated format?

```
output:= "key1,key2,key3"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iterate in a loop and append key to string:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var userinputmap = make(map[string]string)

    userinputmap["key1"] = "value1"
    userinputmap["key2"] = "value2"
    userinputmap["key3"] = "value3"
    output :=""
    for key,_ := range userinputmap {
    output +=(key+",")
    }
    output = output[:len(output)-1]
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
That works. 
By the way, what is the significance of : 
output = output[:len(output)-1] ?

Comment: @pronessssssssssss, it gets rid of the trailing comma, without it, the output would've been: `key2,key3,key1,`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to collect all your keys into a slice and then use `strings.Join` method to join them.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    var userinputmap = make(map[string]string)

    userinputmap["key1"] = "value1"
    userinputmap["key2"] = "value2"
    userinputmap["key3"] = "value3"

    keys := []string {}

    for k, _ := range userinputmap {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }

    keys_string := strings.Join(keys, ",")

    fmt.Println(keys_string)
}
```

Comment: Instead of appending keys, one simple optimization is `keys := make([]string, len(userinputmap))` and just iterate over it with an index and assigning values to a position. This avoids having to reallocate new memory spaces with a dynamically growing slice each time.

Comment: @WillC, yes, pre-allocating memory, is a little bit faster, but I don't think there is a big difference. Amortized time for both approaches is still `O(n)`. Also, note that the accepted answer is making a copy a string each time it adds a new element, thus leading to `O(n*n)` time complexity. I don't think OP is concerned with performance.